# How to save information to LevelDB and then process this information in another route?

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

I want to save information being processed to a level DB, right now what I have is

```
from(sourceUri)
                
                .transacted()
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, HashMap::class.java)
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "input ${body}")
                <not sure what to put here>
                .end()
```

So what do i put there to save the data incoming into a levelDB? I dont want to use aggregator as it doesn't fit what im doing so at the moment I need to save it into the database. Then i want to make another route using a quartz2 timer to process everything inside this database every minute.

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=30+*+*+?+*+*+*")
    .bean(processData)
    .to("activemq:output");
```